# Determining Spanning Set, Basis and Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, vectors

For the subset $Y$ of $\mathbb R^5$ given below, find a spanning set and a basis, and hence determine its dimension.

$Y = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 ) \in \mathbb R^5 |x_1 +x_3 = 0, x_1 −x_2 +x_5 = 0\}.$

First I tried to find the spanning set. I used elimination. I have $x_1 = -x_3$ and $x_2 = -x_3 + x_5$. This gives $Y = \{(-x_3,-x_3+x_5,x_3,x_4,x_5 ) \} = x_1(0,0,0,0,0) + x_2(0,0,0,0,0) + x_3(-1,-1,1,0,0)+x_4(0,0,0,1,0)+x_5(0,1,0,0,1)$.

So, I believe we can write $Y=$span$\{(-1,-1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0,1) \}$.

I already know that $\{(-1,-1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0,1) \}$ is a spanning set for $Y$. Since these three vectors are linearly independent, we must have that $\{(-1,-1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0,1) \}$ is also a basis for $Y$, with dim($Y$)$=3$.

Comment: What's your question? Your work is correct.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic I wanted to know if my working was correct. Thanks for your reply. Was that the best way of answering the question ? As in, have I actually answered why that is a spanning set

Comment: Yes, I'd say your approach is quite good. The set you've found is a spanning set by default, since you're able to write $Y = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the vectors you've described. Note that finding a spanning set is not so difficult since the standard basis of $\Bbb R^5$, or even the whole of $\Bbb R^5$, would be a spanning set (immediate from the definition.) To calculate the dimension of $Y$, however, you must find a *minimal* spanning set, which you have done! To see that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is *minimal*, note that if you remove any $v_i$ from this set (1/2)

Comment: then the resulting set no longer spans $Y$. (2/2)

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic I understand everything now. Thank you!